# Line Integral of Vector Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

this question comes from my practice exam for vector calculus and I just have no clue on how to do it. Can somebody provide me with some hints on how to do it? Thanks!
Here is the link to the screenshot of the question[line integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UhSA.jpg)

Comment: It is against MSE practice to link to questions: you should learn enough MathJax to transcribe the question here. But the central hint is: use the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question at here so I am not very familiar with the rules yet. Thanks for the advice and hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First observe the vector field
\begin{align}
\vec{F}(x, y) = e^{\frac{1}{2}\cos^3(x+y)}\vec{i}+e^{\frac{1}{2}\cos^3(x+y)}\vec{j} =: M(x, y)\vec{i}+N(x, y)\vec{j}
\end{align}
is globally defined on the plane. Next, observe $\partial_y M = \partial_x N$ which means $\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field. Hence there exists $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{F} =\nabla f$. More importantly, since
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 
\end{align}
then we see that $f(x, y) = g(x+y)$ for some $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Finally, by the fundamental theorem of line integral, we get that
\begin{align}
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = f(1, -1)-f(0, 0) = g(1-1)-g(0+0) = 0.
\end{align}
Likewise, for the other curve we see that
\begin{align}
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = f(-\pi, 2\pi)-f(2\pi, -\pi)= g(-\pi+2\pi)-g(2\pi-\pi) = 0.
\end{align}